# Accessing Actiontec modem screens via PHP

Tags: php, curl, router

I have an Actiontec V1000H router.  I want to access its "WAN Ethernet Status" page using a script (which will extract the sent and received packet counts for plotting).  From a browser, this URL works fine:

```
http://192.168.1.1/modemstatus_wanethstatus.html
```

But, when I use that URL in my script, I nearly always get the main screen.  (It works on rare occasions.)  Here's my script:

```
$wanStatusUrl = "http://192.168.1.1/modemstatus_wanethstatus.html";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $wanStatusUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'admin:myPassword');
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I need help accessing the modemstatus_wanethstatus.html page.  I believe the issue is due to some idiocycracy of the modem.

Comment: I think you need to specify a CURL cookiefile with the option `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE`.

Comment: I've tried CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE with '' and 'temp' -- still get the wrong page.  But, I suspect something like this (which browsers do but I'm not) is the trouble.

Comment: can you post the HTTP headers before, during and after your request?

Comment: Dan: Since I'm setting the headers myself using url_setopt, I don't think there are any others.  How would get any more info than than that?

Comment: I mean the headers you get as a response, not the headers you send as a request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main screen has a "login" button, and adding the equivalent of that prior to accessing the WAN Status screen made it work.  So, for the record:

```
// login
$loginUrl = 'http://192.168.1.1/login.cgi?inputUserName=admin&inputPassword=myPassword&nothankyou=1';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// get status page
$wanStatusUrl = "http://192.168.1.1/modemstatus_wanethstatus.html";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $wanStatusUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // so curl_exec returns the response
$responseText = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// print $responseText; // contains wanEthStatus_ReceivedPackets and wanEthStatus_SendPackets

// get the two packet counts ... wanEthStatus_ReceivedPackets and wanEthStatus_SendPackets
preg_match( "/wanEthStatus_ReceivedPackets.*?\'(\d+)\';.*?\'(\d+)\';.*?wanEthStatus_TimeSpan/s", $responseText, $matches );
print_r( $matches );
```

"Man Always Wins in the End."

Answer (score 0):

Use this so that curl return you the html source as response into your `$output`:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

Comment: That affects where the output goes, but the page returned is still the wrong page.